# How to run a cron job starting at 0:30 and repeat every 2 hours?

Tags: google-app-engine, cron

I already have a job that starts every 2 hours.

```
cron:
- description: Scrape every 2 hours
  url: /generator
  schedule: every 2 hours synchronized
```

Now I would like to start another job around 30 min after the the job above.
So I thought I start at 00:30 and repeat every 2 hours. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can set scheduled tasks like this

```
every 2 hours from 00:30 to 23:30
```

For more details refer https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron#Python_app_yaml_The_schedule_format

Answer (score 0):

If you need exact start time, do this:

```
every 30 minutes from 00:30 to 23:30
```

If you need to start 30 minutes after the previous job is completed, do not use cron. Start a task (Task API) scheduled for 30 minutes in future at the end of the previous job.

Comment: Would you please illustrate that with some code how you would schedule a push-queue task 30 min in future? (preferably in Python if possible)

Comment: You can use either coundown or eta depending on your requirements: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/tasks#countdown_arg